# Windows batch file script - Fan Control Speed Dell R710 based on Abmient Temp

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a Windows batch file script to generate some output actions for a Dell R710 based on Ambient Temps.  I have the IMPITools installed and working on the system (it generates the ambient temp output to a file) and have snipets of code, I'm struggling to put it together to do an action based on the value that comes back.

What do I have so far:

```
REM Find out what the Ambient Temp is..
ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IP Address> -U root -P calvin sensor reading "Ambient Temp" > temp.txt
```

--> This gives me an output file which gives the temp ambient (of the motherboard):

```
Ambient Temp     | 22
```

*What I would like to do is read the file string into a local variable in the ms dos.bat file and then based on the value - get the actual reading part of the string e.g. `22` into a local variable `%temp%` for example .*

*Can someone help me work out how to do this so I can get this part of the text file or IMPI tool output into a local variable ?*

Based on the output of the reading, I would like different actions to be performed:

```
If "%temp%" >50
ECHO The AC is Broken - Call an Engineer and power down the server !
GOTO END

If "%temp%" >30
ECHO Turn the AC Up to MAX - its getting toasty in here 
GOTO END

If "%temp%" >25
ECHO Turn the AC On.
GOTO END

If "%temp%" >= 20 or "%temp%" <= 24
ECHO Turn the AC and Heating Off - save energy and the planet
GOTO END

If "%temp%" < 20
ECHO Turn the heating on - its getting cold in here and close the door !
GOTO END

If "%temp%" < 5
ECHO Call the engineer to fix the heating - its almost freezing in here !
GOTO END

:END
```

-->> Update on progress 02/09/2021 <<--
Okay, I've managed to get the a for statement to work for this part of the first part..

```
REM FAN CONTROL ACTIVATED
SET LOCAL

REM Get the current reading of the Temp to the file 
dell_bmc\ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IP> -U <UserName> -P <Pwd> sensor reading "Ambient Temp" >> temp.txt

REM Get the number of lines in the temp.txt file
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%i IN ('find /v /c "temp" temp.txt') DO set /a lines=%%i

REM Use Set /A to subtract 5 from the line number to get how many lines to skip from the file
set /a startLine=%lines% - 5

REM Set a counter to get the last 5 Temp Readings and Current One
set Cnt=0

REM Use "More" to read the file and skip a number of lines in the file
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%A IN ('more /E +%startLine% temp.txt') DO (
REM You would use the "TYPE" version if you were only reading one value from the file.
REM FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%A IN ('type temp.txt') DO (
  Echo %%A - A Value
  CALL SET Temp_Current=%%A
  set /a Cnt+=1
  call Set Temp_Current[%%Cnt%%]=%%A
)
ECHO Temp-Current[0] %Temp_Current%
Echo Temp-Current[1] %Temp_Current[1]%
Echo Temp-Current[2] %Temp_Current[2]%
Echo Temp-Current[3] %Temp_Current[3]%
Echo Temp-Current[4] %Temp_Current[4]%
Echo Temp-Current[5] %Temp_Current[5]%
CALL SET Temp_Current = %Temp_Current[5]%
REM Temp-Current [5] is the latest temp reading as its the last line in the file

REM To stop the file getting to big - we will re-output the temp.txt file and ensure it only contains up-to the last 10 readings.
SET /a TargetLeft=%lines%/5-1
SET /a NewStartPos=%TargetLeft%*5
more /E +%NewStartPos% temp.txt >temp2.txt
REM  Replace the file with limited number of lines that was generated to be the new temp.txt file output 
COPY temp2.txt temp.txt /Y
```

How do I now implement the logic check block algorithm part - as you indicated IF could not be used to check the value of the %Temp_Current% to perform the actions I would like to perform ?

Comment: Is this really for MS-DOS, and if so, which version. If this is for running within Windows instead, _(you have, after all, included a [[tag:windows]] tag too)_, please [edit] your question to remove the [[tag:dos]] tag and all references to the very old MicroSoft Disk Operating System. There is a description for each tag that you use, if you are unsure whether it is suitable for the audiences to whom you are pitching your question. Also if this is for Windows, there are thousands of questions and answers under the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, which save the result of a command to a variable.

Comment: This is for MS-DOS (from v9 onwards).  The Windows tag has been included (so it will not be confused with DR-DOS or IBM-DOS).  This version of MS-DOS is for "older" O/S such as Windows NT/2000/XP - so the tag is probably fine.

There may be  answers on how to "get a result of a command to a variable", however this also requires sub-stringing the output, and/or reading the output of a file into a variable and I'm not sure if the logic of the IF "%var" > NN would work in this case, based on what I've written, so a sanity check here would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not fine, there is no such thing ad MS-DOS 9 onwards, I have removed your invalid tag. What you are looking for is the Windows command line, i.e. command.com, or more correctly based upon your v9 statement, `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I suspect you're talking about [DOS9](https://github.com/TSnake41/dos9-code) which has been renamed to [PicoBat](https://github.com/darkbatcher/picobat) and isn't _quite_ CMD but is close enough based on your code.

Comment: The logic of using the `If` command is no good to you, until you have generated the variable which contains the output from your command, in this case `22`. You need to do this in steps, it is no good asking for the logic of performing commands against the output, if you have not yet generated that output in a format you can perform those commands against. Like I said, first use the search facility to locate questions and answers which parses and outputs the result of a command to a variable. Once you have succeeded in doing that, then you can ask how to use the `If` logic successfully.

Comment: Okay- I have added the code, that I've managed to get parsing the output from the file using a FOR statement with TOKENS to get the output value into a variable.   How do I now use the IF statement logic to make the various actions as required ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first script to control the fan speed based on the temperature on one of the processors on my Poweredge R720xd, it might work with other dell servers and workstations.  You just need to have ipmitool on the same folder (it can be downloaded from dell emc website)

```
ECHO OFF
SET LOCAL
CLS
REM Set Server IP address, Username and Password for the IPMI connection
set serverip=192.168.1.211
set username=root
set password=Password
REM Set Temperature thresholds and fan speeds in decimal and hex
set temp1=45
set fan1=30
set hex1=0x1e
set temp2=50
set fan2=35
set hex2=0x23
set temp3=55
set fan3=45
set hex3=0x28
set temp4=60
set fan4=55
set hex4=0x37
set temp5=65
set fan5=65
set hex5=0x41
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO    Dell Poweredge Manual Fan Speed Control Script v1.1
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO.
ECHO  Setting Manual Fan Speed Control
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00
ECHO.
ECHO  Setting fans speed at %fan1%%%
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff %hex1%
timeout /t 3
:temperature_check
CLS
REM erase previous temp.txt file
del temp.txt
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO    Dell Poweredge Manual Fan Speed Control Script v1.1
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO.
ECHO  Reading Temperature Sensors and Creating Temp.txt file
REM Saves current temperatures to temp.txt file
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% sdr type temperature > temp.txt
ECHO  Reading Fan Speed Sensors and Other PSU and Temp Sensors
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% sdr list full
REM Reads current temperature from temp.txt
set Cnt=0
set Temp_Current[3]=0
set Temp_Current[4]=0
REM Get the number of lines in the temp.txt file
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%i IN ('find /v /c "temp" temp.txt') DO set /a lines=%%i
set /a startLine=%lines%
FOR /F "tokens=9 delims= " %%A IN ('type temp.txt') DO (
REM  Echo %%A
  CALL SET Temp_Current=%%A
  set /a Cnt+=1
  call Set Temp_Current[%%Cnt%%]=%%A
)
Echo  [CPU 0] Current Temperature %Temp_Current[3]%
Echo  [CPU 1] Current Temperature %Temp_Current[4]%
if %Temp_Current[4]% GTR %temp5% goto temp05
if %Temp_Current[4]% GTR %temp4% goto temp04
if %Temp_Current[4]% GTR %temp3% goto temp03
if %Temp_Current[4]% GTR %temp2% goto temp02
if %Temp_Current[4]% == %temp2% goto temp01
if %Temp_Current[4]% LSS %temp2% goto temp01
ECHO Script is not working!
goto end
:temp01
Echo  Current CPU Temperature is below %temp1% degrees Celsius.
Echo  Setting Fans Speed at %fan1%%%
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff %hex1%
timeout /t 3
goto temperature_check
:temp02
Echo  Current CPU Temperature is below %temp2% degrees Celsius.
Echo  Setting Fans Speed at %fan2%%%
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff %hex2%
timeout /t 3
goto temperature_check
:temp03
Echo  Current CPU Temperature is below %temp3% degrees Celsius.
Echo  Setting Fans Speed at %fan3%%%
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff %hex3%
timeout /t 3
goto temperature_check
:temp04
Echo  Current CPU Temperature is below %temp4% degrees Celsius.
Echo  Setting Fans Speed at %fan4%%%
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff %hex4%
timeout /t 3
goto temperature_check
:temp05
Echo  Current CPU Temperature is below %temp5% degrees Celsius.
Echo  Setting Fans Speed at %fan5%%%
ipmitool -I lanplus -H %serverip% -U %username% -P %password% raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff %hex5%
timeout /t 3
goto temperature_check

:end
Echo Ending Script
Pause
```